# Gmail atom feed with OAuth receive 401 error

Tags: oauth-2.0, rss, gmail, atom-feed

my app is experiencing the issue using Gmail atom feed with OAuth, an error message is "401 unauthorized".  The functionality has stopped working since last week.

The error message is like below.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have noticed that there were other people as well on stackoverflow that had the same experience and people have reported that Google engineers are working on it.
[a link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24367846/1600481)

My question is, has this fix been released yet? Is there any official site to show the progress/currently working on this fix?

Thanks

Comment: This issue has been fixed now.  Gmail rss feed is now working on my app :)